# Reference ID in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a feeling the answer is simple and documented, but I'm absolutely missing it:

Is there a way, using Python and webapp through Google App Engine, to pass the id field of a record to the template? I'm fairly new to the app engine, and yes, I have searched all around the Google Documentation to find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reference it through record.key().id(). I just found this RIGHT AFTER I posted this question (as luck would have it). Sorry for wasting anybody's time.

Comment: Oh wow... Didn't didn't see your answer while submitting mine... Deleting

Comment: Note that these IDs are unique across all kinds, so for any given kind, the entities' IDs may not be a natural progression (`1, 2, 3, ...`).  Some numbers will be missing because they'll have been assigned to entities of other kinds.

Comment: Nikhil: that's not correct.  IDs aren't even unique within a kind; they're unique within a kind and entity group.  The reason they're not sequential is that an instance is allocated a large block of IDs, and unused ones aren't assigned to later instances.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the built-in Django 0.96 templates, you can access the ID (assuming the entity has one; it might have a key name instead if you saved it with one) with `{{entity.key.id}}`.